# Sed/Tr to sort api output

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, tr

I need help to sort api output and sort and get latest

```
{
 "name" : "xyz.abc",
 "tags" : [ "1.0.33", "1.0.35", "1.0.47", "1.0.63", "1.0.56", "1.0.45", "1.0.58", "1.0.31", "1.0.39", 
 "1.0.30", "1.0.51", "1.0.41", "1.0.46", "1.0.32", "1.0.64", "1.0.65", "1.0.67", "1.0.42", "1.0.36", 
 "1.0.37", "1.0.53", "1.0.43", "1.0.44", "1.0.48", "1.0.49" ]
}
```

I tried -

```
     cat test2.text | grep tags | tr -d '[|]' | sed -n '/ *"tags" *: *"/ { s///; s/".*//; p; }'`
     1.0.33
```

Output needed:

```
      1.0.67
```

Comment: If you're parsing JSON, use a tool specialized for that purpose: `jq`.

Comment: Not all of the tag values are on the same line as `"tags"`

Comment: What's the purpose of `|` in `tr -d '[|]'`? That character doesn't appear in the API output, why do you need to delete it?

Comment: I think his goal was to delete all the characters other than the number to try to sort it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ruby` with the built-in JSON library like so:

```
$ ruby -r json -e 'puts JSON.parse($<.read)["tags"]' file | sort | tail -n 1
1.0.67
```

Or, entirely in `ruby` without the pipe:

```
$ ruby -r json -e 'puts JSON.parse($<.read)["tags"].sort_by{|s| s.split[-1]}[-1]' file
```

Or, use `jq` and `sed`:

```
$ jq -c '.tags | sort' file | sed -nE 's/.*"([0-9.]*)"]$/\1/p'
1.0.67
```

Or just use `jq`'s `max`:

```
$ jq -c '.tags | max' file 
"1.0.67"                     # you can remove the " with sed
```

---

These work with your example but will fail with other usual version strings. Such as, is `1.0.255` a later or earlier version than `1.0.67`?

If you want to do a proper version sort (so `1.0.255` sorts later than `1.0.67` for example), you can do that in Ruby with:

```
$ ruby -r json -e 'puts JSON.parse($<.read)["tags"].sort_by{|s| Gem::Version.new(s)}[-1]' file
```

Many versions of Unix `sort` also support version sorting so if you want to support typical version strings with `-V` argument to sort pipelines above.

Answer (score 1):

Use tools that understand JSON (jq) and versions (GNU sort).

```
jq -r .tags[] test2.text | sort -V | tail -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cat test2.text | jq .tags | tr -d '"|,|[|]' | awk '{print $1}' | sort | tail -1
```

Output:

```
1.0.67
```